# Compare image of type image by image stored in file system

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

If i have the following case :

set of images(JPG) stored as file system .every image has a name like this :

identifier concatenated with student number

Ex : `356782377.jpg`

and i have a table with the following structure :

```
TransTime       DateTime
Photo           image
Identifier      int
StudentNumber   int
```

---

Every Trans has a a student image in db table and the equivalent in file system.
initially the table record is complete except the student number .

EX :

```
    TransTime             Photo    identifier    student number
2016-08-05 18:39:00       image      35678             ??
```

---

I want to extract the student number `(2377)` part from image file name in file system through comparing the photo of type (image) in db by the image stored in file system and set the student number for the transaction in db .

I thought to convert both ( the image in db and the image in file system) to bytes and compare them to update the null student by the correct number.
 Is that the most suitable solution to my problem ?

Comment: You should stop using the image datatype. It has been deprecated for over a decade now (since sql server 2005) in favor of varbinary(max). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange : I have to adapt with this type because it's the db of a machine it's not my db

Comment: There are multiple algorithms comparing two files more efficient than comparing bytes. What kind of problem are you hoping to solve apart from comparing two images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you need to compare two files for equality, especially if you expect the comparison to be performed multiple times on the same file, it is best to generate a hash digest of the file and store it along with the file in the database. Then, when you need to compare a new file with ones in the database, you can generate the digest of the new file and compare that to the ones in the db.

A SHA256 digest uses 32 bytes. An MD5 hash uses 16. Since you don't need this to be crypto-grade you can go with MD5 if you expect to need to make lots of comparisons.

If you can't modify the database schema and/or data to add the digests then what you're proposing is probably your only option.

Comment: I want to compare image stored in file system by image of type`image` stored in db . and it's the db of a machine so i have to adapt myself with this type

Answer (score 1):

Are the identifiers unique? Do you really want to binary compare the files, or do you just want to get the student number for a given image?

If the identifiers are unique, and you just want the student number (do not need to ensure the binary files are identical), I would just go through the filenames on the file system and update the DB as necessary.